# Slow browsing but fast torrent

Tags: speed, bittorrent, browsing, internet-speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Browsing/Direct Download, but Fast Bittorrent Download](https://superuser.com/questions/123296/slow-browsing-direct-download-but-fast-bittorrent-download)

I know this has been already asked, but still I can't fix this.

[Slow Browsing/Direct Download, but Fast Bittorrent Download](https://superuser.com/questions/123296/slow-browsing-direct-download-but-fast-bittorrent-download) (solutions don't work for me)
[Internet connection slow, unreliable, but torrent speeds unaffected](https://superuser.com/questions/375952/internet-connection-slow-unreliable-but-torrent-speeds-unaffected) (similar problem, solution doesn't help either)

I am experiencing very slow browsing (~1Mbit max), but torrents are still going well (~7Mbit, that is also what I'm paying for).

Had this problem with two different routers. Also I'm sure the DSL is okay, a technician came for this very problem and confirmed that up to the modem the line is good.

I did try by playing with the MTU but that didn't work.

Do you have any suggestion?

**Edit**: I tried downloading something with Bittorrent and checked out the connections list. Each connection stops at 100kb or under. This maybe explains why I'm having problems while browsing or downloading directly.

Comment: First I assume you don't run them simultaneously.
Have you tested it with SpeedTest.net?
Have you tested it with another computer?

BTW, Playing with the MTU is only relevant when you're trying to accelerate you LAN.

Comment: @EliadTech: tried with two other computers. With SpeedTest.net, sometimes it's 1Mbit, sometimes 1.50 or 2Mbit. Yes, I'm not running them simultaneously.

Comment: Is DSL router creating ppp tunel or you are dialing from your PC? How looks your network, mean which devices you use above dsl router?

Comment: I'm not sure about ppp, in my router I can read "PPPoE" under the label "type", so I assume the answer is yes. There are three computers connected to the router via wireless, nothing else.

Comment: The speed limit can be set as well on the other side, here I mean the limitations set on the server/hosting used by the sites. Do you experience any issues watching video on youtube?

Comment: Yes. I am experiencing issues with everything other than Bittorrent. Also ftp is under 1Mbit

Comment: Summarising: You have problems with **all** connections being limited to 100KB/sec. Including torrents. But the slowness does not affect torrent downloads since the torrents use a lot of simultaneous connections (each of which is still capped at about 100KB/sec which is about equal to 1Mbit/sec).

Comment: @Hennes: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Have you tested to see if your ISP is traffic shaping? http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/bttest.php

Comment: @OliverG: I tried. Upload: "There is no indication that your ISP rate limits your uploads.". Download: "The measurement data is too noisy to detect whether your ISP rate limits your download traffic.". On a side note, upload speed is unaffected.

Comment: Tried again: "There is no indication that your ISP rate limits your uploads." on both upload and download.

Comment: Interesting about the noise though. Have you contacted your ISP to determine that the line is in fact working correctly? Your problem sounds suspiciously similar to one i had at an office where I worked. We went through every solution known to mankind, before finding out it was our ISP.

Comment: Also, what kind of responses do you get when pinging remote servers? Have you tried changing your DNS to some OpenDNS servers to check if the problem persists?

Comment: Yes. I used both OpenDNS and GoogleDNS. Really, I have no clue. The technician also plugged a device (like a smartphone) to the wall and confirmed a 700/800kb bandwidth. But download is still stuck at 100kb.